# How does tuple comparison work under the hood

Tags: swift, tuples

```
let p1 = (name: "John", age:12)
let p2 = (color: "Red", size:12)


if p1 == p2 {
    print("equal")
}else {
    print("not equal")
}
```

I was expecting these two tuples to be incompatible due the different parameter names and the code to not compile. But it works fine. Curious to know how.

Does Swift automatically create `==` operators based on the property types and then just do a simple `lhs` vs. `rhs`. Is that it?

**EDIT:**

```
func givePerson() -> (name: String, age: Int)? {
    return ("alex", 2)
}

func extract() {
    var p3 : (Name: String, age: Int)

    if let person = giveName() as? (Name: String, age: Int) {
        p3 = person
        print(p3)
    }else {
        print("p3 not defined")
    }

}

extract() // p3 not defined
```

My `extract` function fails, just because I got the name of the arity incorrect. Is that also expected? How is that different from the tuple comparison?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/bafb963d7bc3ef4769e20211b558076042d50582/stdlib/public/core/Tuple.swift.gyb#L108-L143 :)

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for teaching me how to link to multiple lines in Github + existence of a word named 'arity' :D

Comment: Welcome to 10k!

Comment: @Hamish Can you please see my edit?

Comment: @Honey Tuple labels are a weird part of the language. There are conversions that can strip labels and conversions that can add arbitrary labels, but the direct renaming of labels isn't allowed. For example: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/2649a0f94dcaadab744c27975945272d. So yeah, arguably the behaviour you're getting is expected.

Comment: @Hamish Wanna cook that up into an answer?

Comment: @Alexander Sure thing!

Comment: https://github.com/Flying-Toast/swift-sucks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library [defines tuple comparison operators](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/bafb963d7bc3ef4769e20211b558076042d50582/stdlib/public/core/Tuple.swift.gyb#L108-L143) for 2 element tuples up to and including 6 element tuples. It does this through using the metaprogramming tool [GYB](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e9817b027fc4fdd1076491527345130fbc5de9dd/utils/gyb.py) (Generate Your Boilerplate) which allows embedded Python code to generate a file from a template.

The resulting tuple comparison operators end up looking like:

```
public func == <A, B>(lhs: (A, B), rhs: (A, B)) -> Bool

public func == <A, B, C>(lhs: (A, B, C), rhs: (A, B, C)) -> Bool

public func == <A, B, C, D>(lhs: (A, B, C, D), rhs: (A, B, C, D)) -> Bool

// ...
```

So with your code:

```
let p1 = (name: "John", age: 12)
let p2 = (color: "Red", size: 12)

if p1 == p2 {
    print("equal")
} else {
    print("not equal")
}
```

The compiler will call the two element tuple comparison operator. You'll note that none of the defined tuple comparison operators use tuple labels for their parameters. The reason why both
 `(name: String, age: Int)` and `(color: String, size: Int)` can be passed to `(A, B)` is that the compiler implements an implicit conversion that can strip a tuple of its labels. So both arguments have their labels stripped and are both passed as `(String, Int)`.

That's what makes the following legal:

```
let p1 = (name: "John", age: 12)
let p2: (String, Int) = p1 // Legal.
```

Things get weirder with the fact that the compiler also has an implicit conversion that can *add* arbitrary labels to a tuple:

```
let p1 = ("John", 12)
let p2: (foo: String, bar: Int) = p1 // Legal.
```

However the direct renaming of labels is forbidden:

```
// Indirect renaming ✅
let p1 = (name: "John", age: 12)
let p2: (String, Int) = p1
let p3: (foo: String, bar: Int) = p2

// Put together ✅
let p4: (foo: String, bar: Int) = p1 as (String, Int)

// Direct renaming ❌
let p4 = (name: "John", age: 12)
let p5: (foo: String, bar: Int) = p4
```

And that's the behaviour you're seeing with your `as?` cast. Like the above example, first coercing to the unlabelled form works:

```
func givePerson() -> (name: String, age: Int)? {
  return ("alex", 2)
}

func extract() {
  var p3: (Name: String, age: Int)
  if let person = givePerson() as (String, Int)? as? (Name: String, age: Int) {
    p3 = person
    print(p3)
  } else {
    print("p3 not defined")
  }

}

extract() // (Name: "alex", age: 2)
```

Comment: took me a while to notice that you got to make my 2nd question work

Comment: I understand the behavior we're seeing. But is there any reason why implicit works and direct renaming doesn't? Is there anywhere in the Swift repo that implies such?

Comment: @Honey It's just a restriction the Swift compiler enforces – [implemented here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e73127265e87e1b4122ce5f150b48c48a3d49a3a/lib/Sema/TypeCheckConstraints.cpp#L161-L164) if you're interested. In isolation, I think it's a sensible rule – labels are part of a tuple's type and you shouldn't be able to rename them implicitly. However, as shown, it can be easily bypassed. It would probably make more sense if only the label removal conversion was implicit, with the label adding and (if added) label renaming conversions having to be explicitly spelled by the user.

Comment: now that I'm thinking about it, it does make sense to not allow name conversions. Because if you were accessing it with `.name`, now you have to use `.Name` and that would create unexpected results...

Answer (score 2):

Tuples have `==` operators defined (for tuples of arity 2 to 7), but since tuples can't conform to protocols, they're not `Equatable`.

The standard library just defines 6 seperate `==` operators, each taking two tuples of arity 2, 3, ... , 7.